# Fail to download plugin [python] into /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache16281144584832771696.tmp

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

After setting up pipeline my pipeline fails showing followings output

Injecting SonarQube environment variables using the configuration: sonar-server
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh

- /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/sonar-scanner/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectName=Netflix -Dsonar.projectKey=Netflix
  INFO: Scanner configuration file: /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
  INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
  INFO: SonarScanner 5.0.1.3006
  INFO: Java 17.0.8.1 Eclipse Adoptium (64-bit)
  INFO: Linux 5.19.0-1025-aws amd64
  INFO: User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
  INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 9.9.2.77730
  INFO: Default locale: "en", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
  INFO: Load global settings
  INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=103ms
  INFO: Server id: 147B411E-AYtwIQNkc_xjmO-3Z1qY
  INFO: User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
  INFO: Load/download plugins
  INFO: Load plugins index
  INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=69ms
  INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=2021ms
  INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
  INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  INFO: Total time: 3.925s
  INFO: Final Memory: 6M/27M
  INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader@670b40af-org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerPluginRepository': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download plugin [python] into /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache16281144584832771696.tmp

.....................................................................................